# Couting of array according to hash key in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-2.4

I have an array

```
data = [{:user=>1399, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10270},
        {:user=>3112, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10271},
        {:user=>1455, :job=>10271}]
```

Where 1399, 2614, 3112, 1455 are user ids and 10270, 10271 are job ids.

I want to show the number of jobs per user regardless of the job id.

Expected result:

```
1399 => 1
2614 => 2 # because 2614 has 2 two jobs
3112 => 1
1455 => 1
```

i need this in an array

Comment: _"i need this in an array"_ – your expected result looks more like a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `group_by` the `user` key and then count the number of elements in each group:

IMPROVED SOLUTION

```
data = [{:user=>1399, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10270}, {:user=>3112, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10271}, {:user=>1455, :job=>10271}]
data.group_by {|e| e[:user]}
  .transform_values(&:size)
# => {1399=>1, 2614=>2, 3112=>1, 1455=>1}
```

ORIGINAL SOLUTION

```rb
data = [{:user=>1399, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10270}, {:user=>3112, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10271}, {:user=>1455, :job=>10271}]
data.group_by {|e| e[:user]}
  .map{|id, a| [id, a.size]}
  .to_h
# => {1399=>1, 2614=>2, 3112=>1, 1455=>1}
```

Comment: Consider replacing the last two lines with `.transform_values(&:size)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the user ids via [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#map-method) and then let Ruby count the occurrences via [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#tally-method):

```
data.map { |h| h[:user] } #=> [1399, 2614, 3112, 2614, 1455]
    .tally                #=> {1399=>1, 2614=>2, 3112=>1, 1455=>1}
```

Comment: It show undefined method 'tally' may be reason is i am new to ruby.
But this works
data = [{:user=>1399, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10270}, {:user=>3112, :job=>10270}, {:user=>2614, :job=>10271}, {:user=>1455, :job=>10271}]
data.group_by {|e| e[:user]}
  .map{|id, a| [id, a.size]}
  .to_h

Comment: @MohammadYusuf seems like you're using an older version of Ruby. `Enumerable#tally` was introduced in Ruby 2.7.

Comment: Thatswhy,  i am using 2.4. Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to round-out what I believe are the standard ways of doing this.

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:user]] += 1 }
  #=> {1399=>1, 2614=>2, 3112=>1, 1455=>1}
```

It works with older versions of Ruby and avoids the construction of a temporary array or hash.

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes an argument and no block. If a hash is defined `h = Hash.new(0)` then later, if (and only if) `h` has no key `k`, `h[k] = 0` is executed before `h[k] += 0`. `h` is sometimes called a *counting hash*.